# Ruby/Rails way to enable resource availability on certain dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, datetime, rubygems

What tools should I be exploring in Ruby/Rails to store the dates or 'availability' of a Model object?

For example, say in my Clown Booking Service I want to mark each of my many clowns with its availability (and pricing) for certain times of the day and certain days of the week...including additional anomalies for holidays.

How best to approach this in Ruby/Rails environment?  Any 'magic' gems I should be looking into?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want some `ical` or a similar date format serialized into a column, [see here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods/composed_of). [There are a bunch of ical libs out there](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=icalendar). Probably there is a better appointment format, but I don't know it (yet).